# ValueError: Precomputed matrix must be a square matrix. Input is a 500x29243 matrix

Tags: python, information-retrieval

Question about the code for `ECIR 2018` paper `"Cross-lingual Document Retrieval using Regularized Wasserstein Distance"`.
When I run the code : `"python emd.py concept_net_1706.300.en concept_net_1706.300.fr wiki_data/wikicomp.enfr.2k.en wiki_data/wikicomp.enfr.2k.fr 500 french"`

The following questions appear:

```
/home/xzy/xzy_py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py:167: EfficiencyWarning: Precomputed sparse input was not sorted by data.
EfficiencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "emd.py", line 56, in
clf.fit(X_train_idf[:instances], np.ones(instances))
File "/home/xzy/docretrieve/wass_funcs.py", line 120, in fit
return super(WassersteinDistances, self).fit(X, y)
File "/home/xzy/xzy_py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py", line 1155, in fit
return self._fit(X)
File "/home/xzy/xzy_py/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py", line 409, in _fit
.format(X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))
ValueError: Precomputed matrix must be a square matrix. Input is a 500x29243 matrix.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
svclf = SVC(kernel='precomputed')

kernel_train=np.dot(train_set,train_set.T) # modified the train_set

svclf.fit(kernel_train, target_train)

kernel_test=np.dot(test_set,train_set.T) # modified the test_set

pred = svclf.predict(kernel_test)
```

l have met the same problem as picture below.
[image]

And l find an example about sklearn precomputed kernel on github.[sklearn precomputed kernel example](https://gist.github.com/amueller/1351047)

Different from other kernals, the train/test set's form of 'precomputed' should be modified before using svclf.fit and svclf.predict.

Hoping to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, if you change the metric for the knn classifier from precomputed to euclidean. Which is the one they are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).